# Issue with accessing services in kubernetes externally on bare metal

Tags: kubernetes, networking, service, routes, load-balancing

I have a two-node K8S bare metal cluster running k8s v1.18.  I'm using Calico and MetalLB.  Both nodes are deployed on Ubuntu 20.04.  I have a service deployed and MetalLB assigns the external IP.  I can access the service from within the cluster using the external IP without fail. I can even access the service from a couple of external systems however without 100% consistency.
I'm at a loss as where to look to diagnose this issue.  Am I missing some sort of network bridge perhaps on the underlying host OS?

I definitely appreciate any guidance anyone can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Maybe this will help someone pulling out their hair.  As it turns out one of my speakers for my slave node was binding to the wrong physical interface.  So, if you have more than one physical interface, i.e. eth0, eth1, ...,
and they are active, 'ip link show' to confirm, then the sweeper might bind to the wrong interface.

For me, I wasn't using the other interfaces so I simply disabled them.  All is peachy keen now.